# AT&T Assembly Masked Input

Tags: intel, assembly, att

I'm trying to create a simple password program in AT&T Assembly but i'm having trouble with masking an input. What i want to happen is when the user enters characters, they appear on the screen as asterisk'. In intel syntax it's relatively simple:

```
mov ah, 08h
int 21h

mov dl,2ah
mov ah,02h
int 21h
```

This uses the intel command to read an input without echoing it and instead print an asterisk.
I'm trying to solve this problem in AT&T syntax and I'm having some trouble.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool chain are you using? If you're under e.g. Linux `int 21h` won't work even if translated to AT&T syntax.

Comment: No i'm using int 0x80, the code runs. I've just had trouble finding a read no echo syscall in at&t

Comment: That's because it's platform specific. You should include the exact platform you're running under e.g. 32-bit x86 Linux. The answer is going to be the same as for C/C++/etc. and will probably involve tcsetattr. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal) SO question.

Comment: I'm using the "as" compiler on linux x86 with AT%T syntax, if that helps.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble doing? Creating an assembly program? Reading input from that program? Is it just about getting keyboard input without echo?

Comment: Just getting input without echo, i tried to research it as best i could but it just ended up as an intel solution. So i really just need the AT&T version of the intel code above. Or a solution that does the same thing. Only in AT&T. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

**Please correct me if I'm wrong:**

In AT&T assembly hexadecimal is written C-style: `0x30` instead of `30h`. Octals are also like in C, prefixed with a `0`.

And depending on what size memory you are manipulating you have to use that size's postfix on the operand. That means `movl` instead of `mov` on 32bit long memory:

```
8 bits = b      - derived from "byte"
16 bits = w     - derived from "word"
32 bits = l     - I have no idea why 16 bits is usually a "dword"
64 bits = q     - derived from "qword", q for "quad-", so four words in size
```

Also values are prefixed with a dollar sign: `$0x41` (as are variables?) and registers are prefixed with percent signs: `%eax`.

So if I'm reading this correctly your code should be:

```
movl $ah, $0x08
int 0x21

movl $dl, $2ah
movl $ah, $0x02
int $0x21
```

I can't believe I missed this when I wrote the answer, AT&T syntax has reversed source-destination order for instructions with two inputs.

I.e. AT&T is:

```
movl <source>, <dest>
```

while in Intel syntax this will be:

```
mov <dest>, <source>
```

Any corrections are welcome as I'm still learning as well.