# Case insensitive string match

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm struggling with a problem with some AT&T assembly syntax.

Im using the "as" compiler on linux x86.

Im making a password program but it needs to be case insensitive. To clarify, it should evaluate true regardless of the case of any given character.

I have the normal evaluation process working correctly and i have it set up to iterate through a string.

```
#Comparison Routine

    movl $Password, %ebx     #Move the entire hardcoded password into ebx
    movl $buffer_data, %edx  #Move the entire input password into edx
    movl $Password_len, %ecx #Move the length of the input password into ecx

0:  
    movb (%ebx), %al         #Move one byte of the hardcoded password into al
    xorb (%edx), %al         #Compare one byte of the input password to one byte of the hardedcoded
    jz SkipCase              #If they match, jump to SkipCase

##### 

    andb $32, %al   # 
    xorb (%edx), %al

    jz SkipCase
    jnz IncorrectOutput #   

SkipCase:
    inc %ebx                #Iterate through the
    inc %edx                #strings and decrease
    dec %ecx                #the length variable
    jnz 0b                  #if we're not finished, continue
    jmp CorrectOutput       #If all is good, goto CorrectOutput
```

This is the section im struggling with, i can't figure out how to actually convert the character between cases. I'm aware i need to add or subtract 32 from it but something is amiss. Any comments or suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
andb $32, %al   # 
xorb (%edx), %al
```

This is the section for coverting the case, i have tried `add`, `sub`, `and` and `or` and i just cant get it to work. i realise the `jz SkipCase` after this is not nessessary.

The comparison routine is largely based off another question on here that i'll link if nessessary.

Apologies for layout and excessive hashes, bad commenting style i know.

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat misleading, as your problem is clearly not the syntax

Comment: The issue is that i dont know what syntax to use. I think the logic of the program is fine, i just need clarification of what code to use where.

Comment: Well, I would recommend using _cmp_ instead of _sub_ or even _xor_. It has the advantage it doesn't change the operands (like sub does). For the transformation from lower to upper case I recommend `sub $20h` instead of `xor $20h`, unless you want to obfuscate your code. But all this has nothing to do with AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you first try to match the characters 'strictly' and when that fails you proceed with a case insensitive match.

```
andb $32, %al     # this 'and' operation only leaves the $32 bit if it is 
                  # present in al, all other bits are set to 0

# al is now either 0 (for a lower case character)
# or $32 (for an upper case character)

xorb (%edx), %al  # so this operation will become zero if the upper case 
                  # bit ($32) is set in the hardcoded password character
```

What you instead need to do is something like this:

```
xorb $32, %al     # invert case of the character by toggling the upper case bit
cmp (%edx), %al   # try to match again
je SkipCase
```

Hope that helps, I find it really difficult to explain bit operations in a short post like this. :)

---

Also, I presume this is either homework or some sort of excercise because a real password routine would have to be more clever - e.g. only perform the case insensitive check for letters, never digits or other characters.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly, exactally what i was looking for. Yeah instead of it being a usable product its more for the sake of demonstrating the use of assembly. I wonder if i could be cheeky and ask you to have a quick look at this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182165/att-assembly-masked-input which involves a problem i encountered between the difference between AT&T and intel assembly. Thanks for the perfect reply.

Comment: @TheoVate sorry that other question seems related to DOS syscalls which I don't know anything about