# password program in Ubuntu using C language

Tags: c, linux, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide password input on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal)

please give me a solution for a password program in Linux using C language .

when we entering the first letter of password  the window should be shows

```
password:*-
```

instead of the entered letter.

when we enter the next character the window should be shows

```
password**-
```

up to 8 character 
and also verify the password.

Comment: Also see answers here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal), totally same question.

Comment: @Dhaneesh: that's the whole point of the question. Why not read the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using C features :

```
/* no test */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void 
changeMode(bool b)
{
    static struct termios cooked;
    static int raw_actived = 0;

    if (raw_actived == b) return;
    if (b) {
        struct termios raw;

        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &cooked);
        raw = cooked;
        cfmakeraw(&raw);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &raw);
    } else {
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &cooked);
    }   
    raw_actif = b;
}

static void
clean(void)
{
    int c;
    do
        c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void
askPassword(char *s, size_t n)
{
    changeMode(1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s[i] = getchar();
        clean();
        putchar('*');
    }
    changeMode(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
read -s -n 8 -p "password:" mypassword
```

`-s` makes it a password input prompt
`-n` limits the number of characters
`-p STRING` sets the prompt

The inputted password is saved in the `$mypassword` variable for further use.

It's usual on the linux command line that no substitute characters are displayed when inputting a password, so this command doesn't offer an option to do that. Still, it's a good approximation to what you are looking for.

Comment: He clearly stated C language, not shell. however, it's still useful to be called via POSIX system("read ...") call.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili: You meant `popen`? I don't see how is it useful with `system`. Hints?

Comment: Yep you're right, if he wants to read back the entered password, he needs to open a pipe, not just call (though the visual effect can be achieved using the system() call, it probably won't be sufficient).

Answer (score 2):

may be this could help you

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_read_password_without_echoing_c.html

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, so you can try or not.

At the very begining, you have to turn the terminal into non-echo mode. So that, the user's input won't be showed. (Termios settings)

Start with a variable counter. You create a loop (while) and in it, you use read function or getchar to get every single input.
Next, you check if the input is right or not. Writing on the terminal the '*' or nothing.

Comment: the previous post reflects the idea.