# (unix/C) "stty: stdin isn't a terminal" when using system() function

Tags: c, unix, terminal, system

We're reading a file from stdin into `file_buffer`, and then stepping into a method `more`.

As soon as we use `system("stty cbreak -echo");`, the output prints "stty: stdin isn't a terminal" and doesn't set our terminal to the settings we asked for.

This problem only exists when we use standard in. If we use a file argument, the program works fine -- the terminal settings get set, and there is no error message.

So, this is okay: `myprogram file1.txt`

But this is not: `myprogram < file1.txt`

Either way the contents are being read into `file_buffer` before being used at all. What the heck is wrong with using stty if we're taking input from stdin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the standard input is a file, it isn't a terminal, so setting terminal attributes on `stty`'s standard input won't work.

It sounds daft at first, but you will probably find that you can use either `stdout` or `stderr` as the input for `stty` and it will adjust the terminal.  Therefore:

```
system("stty cbreak -echo <&2");
```

is likely to set the terminal characteristics.  If you have a GNU version of `stty`, you could also use:

```
system("stty -F /dev/stderr cbreak -echo");
```

or substitute `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/tty` for `/dev/stderr`.  You could also use any of the named devices instead of the `&2` in the redirection in the first variant.

Answer (score 1):

If you use input redirection or pipes, then `stdin` is *not* a TTY.

You can use [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) to check for that.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! Can I ask how I would turn off echo in the terminal then if we're using stdin? I was doing it with stty before, but if we can't do that with stdin, then what should be used?

Comment: @user1472747 See e.g. [this old SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6869218/440558).