# getchar() is giving output in C

Tags: c, io, getchar

What should this program do,

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{   
  getchar();
}
```

I expect it to show a blank screen until I hit any character on the keyboard. But what it does is quite weird. It displays whatever I press. It never terminates until I press Enter.

As far as I know, getchar() should just read one character. It should not output anything.

> - Why is it printing every character that I input?

Edit:

Why doesn't getchar() stop after reading one character, e.g. in this code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>  

   main()  

   {  

    getchar();  

   printf("Done");  


  }
```

The program should print Done after reading one character.

Comment: It does not print anything. Your terminal driver does.

Comment: @n.m. Terminal driver means my desktop screen?

Comment: So I never need putchar() to output?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: That is known as echoing. You can [disable it too](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal). The `getch` function does exactly what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program won't terminate until `getchar()` completes. `getchar()` does not complete until the input buffer is populated. The input buffer is not populated until you press 'Enter'.

The character you are seeing is the character you are typing. This is default terminal-driven behavior, not driven by your program.

Comment: What does "terminal-driven" mean? Is it my windows feature?

Comment: It is a feature of the terminal, basically the command-line window.

Answer (score 1):

You are pressing key, so your console is showing same character to you. It's expected behaviour. `getch()` will also return ascii value of character that is being printed on screen.

Comment: Do printf() and putchar() also return ascii values?

Comment: `printf()` returns number of character it has printed. `putchar()` returns ascii value.

Answer (score 1):

What `getchar` basically does is reading from stdin. This is a file with file descriptor 0 and it usually refers to the terminal that you type in (unless you change it to some file via `<`, e.g. `cat < sample.txt`). Like with any file, you can call `read` on file 0 - in case of the terminal, `read` will respond as soon as you type something into the terminal **and hit enter**. Unless you do so, the call to `read` on stdin just waits until it gets something to read. This is why your program is waiting: It calls `read` on stdin (file 0), and since stdin is the terminal, `read` will only return when you hit enter.
I hope you have some understanding on file handling, otherwise this answer might confuse you a bit.

Comment: My book doesn't mention that I have to press Enter for getchar to terminate. :(

Comment: Because it is a very basic concept that you have to press enter to send input to your program.

Comment: Your terminal is usually running in 'buffered' and 'local echo' mode. You can change this settings, but how to do so depends on the OS you're using. On DOS/Windows AFAIR you can simply use `getch()` instead of `getchar()`. On Unixes you can either modify termina settings via the `stty` command, or use `curses` or `ncurses` library instead of just using `stdio` `getchar()` that doesn't really know or care what device it is reading from ...