# Understanding getchar() in the character counting program in C

Tags: c, io, getchar

This is a follow-up question of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27336297/3429430) question. There is already a similar question asked([question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183865/3429430)). But I don't get what I want to know from that answer.

From the previous question I come to know that if I type a lot of characters, then they are not made available to getchar(), until I press Enter. So at the very point when I press Enter, all the characters will be made available to getchar()s. Now consider the following program for character counting:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  long nc;
  nc=0;
  while(getchar()!=EOF)
  ++nc;
  printf("    Number of chars are %ld ",nc);
}
```

If I input characters from the command line in the following sequence: {1,2,3,^Z,4,5,Enter}, then in the next line {^Z,Enter}. The output that I expect is: `Number of chars are 6`. But the output that I am getting is `Number of chars are 4`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184020/3429430) explains that when we input`1,2,3,^Z`, then `^Z` acts like `Enter` and 1,2,3 are sent to getchar()s. The while loop of the above written code runs three times. `^Z` is not given to getchar(), so the program doesn't terminate yet. My input was {1,2,3,^Z,4,5,Enter}. After ^Z I had pressed 4,5 and then Enter. Now when I press Enter the characters 4,5 and Enter, should be given to getchar()s and the while loop should execute three times more. Then in the last line I input {^Z,Enter}, since there is no text behind ^Z, it is consider as a character and when I press Enter, this ^Z is given as the input to getchar() and the while loop terminates. In all this, the while loop has executed 6 times, so the variable `nc` should become `6`.

> - Why am I getting `4` as the value of `nc`, rather than `6`.

Comment: Which platform do you use? If you are working with Linux you probably wanted to press ^D instead of ^Z.

Comment: @Marian I'm using Windows-7.

Comment: @Marian You are the author of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27184020/3429430 !! You could shed some light on my problem.

Comment: Windows differs from Linux and the Windows ^Z is not equivalent to Linux ^D. Probably Windows OS forwards the ^Z to the program and then cut the rest of the input.

Comment: If I input {1,2,3,^Z,4,5,Enter} then same {1,2,3,^Z,4,5,Enter} then  {^Z,Enter}. The output is nc=8. Means the input after Enter is not cut.

Comment: As far as I remember ^Z on DOS/Windows is the "End of File" marker and gets interpreted as "no further input beyond this point". So the ^Z itself gets counted but nothing beyond it.

When opening a file yourself you can disable this by adding the "b" modifier to `fopen()` (for `b`inary input), but the standard input stream doesn't have this modifier applied to it.

Comment: ^Z is only counted when there is no text behind it. If ^Z gets counted then the program should terminate eventually, when I input 1,2,3,^Z,4,5,Enter}. But the program takes the next line of the text as further input.

Comment: You must specify the type for `main` (or any other function).

Comment: ^Z not at the beginning of a line does not terminate the input, it only terminates the current line.

Comment: @n.m. Why should I specify the type for `main()`?

Comment: Because the C language standard says so.

Comment: You count `char`s/bytes, not characters. A single character may need have multiple bytes and even multiple Unicode codepoints and you could make a point that a single unicode codepoint may have more than 1 character (depending on your definition of character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some output will help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main (void)
{
  int c, nc = 0;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
    {
      ++nc;
      printf ("Character read: %02x\n", (unsigned) c);
    }
  printf ("Number of chars: %d\n", nc);
}
```

The Windows console views the `^Z` input as "send input before `^Z` to stdin, discard remaining input on the line (including the end-of-line delimiter), and send `^Z`" unless it is at the beginning of a line, in which case it sends `EOF` instead of `^Z`:

```
123^Z45
Character read: 31
Character read: 32
Character read: 33
Character read: 1a
^Z12345
Number of chars: 4
```

Also, Windows always waits for the Enter/Return key, with the exception of very few key sequences like `^C` or `^{Break}`.

Comment: 123^Z45 gives me
Character read: 31
Character read: 32
Character read: 33
Character read: **1a** (instead of 1b). Isn't the value of `^Z` `-1`?

Comment: @user31782 It is `1a`, and I've edited the answer to reflect that. `^A` has a hex code of `01`, `^B` has a hex code of `02`, etc., meaning `^Z` is `1a`. `EOF` is `-1` on Windows, and when you type `^Z` at the beginning of a line, it sends `EOF` instead of hex code `1a`, which might be why you think `^Z` is `-1`.

Comment: What is ASCII value of `^Z`? Is the compiler taking it differently?

Comment: The ascii value of `^Z`is 26(1a in hex). So when ^Z is at the beginning of a line, it takes its value `-1`, otherwise the ACSII value `1a`.

Comment: @user31782 Yes that is correct. `^Z` at the beginning of a line makes `getchar` return `EOF` (-1). Otherwise `getchar` returns the ASCII value of `^Z`.

Answer (score 1):

^Z, or Ctrl-Z, means end-of file for text files (old MS-DOS). getchar() is equivalent to fgetc(stdin) and is often a macro. "fgetc returns the character read as an int or returns EOF to indicate an error or end of file."

See also _set_fmode, however, I am not sure if that changes the behaviour right away or whether you have to close/reopen the file. Not sure either if you can close/reopen stdin (don't do much console programming anymore).

Comment: Could you reword this statement[_So the input library sees end-of-file and then forwards the buffer read so for to the program._] differently. I'm not a native speaker.