# C - making this program portable

Tags: c, unix, conio

## The idea

scanning a password entered by the user and showing `**********` in place of `P@$$w00r_D`

## explaining the code

inside a `while` loop keep scanning the characters using `getch()` and put them into an array `password[]`, until the user press `return`

## The Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define TRUE 1 
#define P_MAX 25

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char password[P_MAX], ch;
   int i = 0;

   puts("Enter the password [MAX 25]: ");
   while (TRUE) {
      if (i < 0) {
         i = 0;
      }//end if
      ch = getch();

      if (ch == 13)//return
         break;
      if (ch == 8) // BACKSPACE
      {
         putch('b');
         putch(NULL);//Overwrite that character by NULL.
         putch('b');
         i--;//Decrement Current Track of Character. (i)
         continue;
      }//end if
          password[i++] = ch;
          ch = '*';
      putch(ch);
   }//end while

   printf("\nPassword Entered : %s", password);//test
   getch();
return 0;
}//end main
```

## Compiling on Unix machine

```
[ar.lnx@host Documents] $ gcc 115.c -o x
115.c:2:18: fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
[ar.lnx@host Documents] $
```

this code works fine on windows, but not in Unix.
any help?

Comment: 1) Use standard C boolean type and constants. Do not use homebrew stuff like `TRUE`. 2) Use only standard C features. 3) In Linux/Unix use PAM.

Comment: `conio.h` is a windows-only library. You'll need to get rid of it and use something in a portable standard.

Comment: @RPGillespie It's actually and old MS-DOS header. It's not a library!

Comment: @iharob I use the word "library" very loosely - It could mean header file, package, object archive, shared object, etc.

Comment: can't we just use `if, #elif, #else, and #endif ` Directives to switch between the libraries? @RPGillespie ?

Comment: Yes, you can use preprocessor directives for windows or linux-only code

Comment: Don't take the "portable" word too seriously. At some point your program interacts with the OS and needs to rely on OS-specific features (the console/terminal in your case). You may use conditional compilation, rely on a lib that does it for you or go with the standards (lowest common denominator).

Comment: Also, have you read this thread yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal

Comment: Thanks for this, this helps a lot

Comment: On UNIX-like systems, you could either directly call termios (the terminal driver) to turn off echoing or you could use a high-level library like curses or getline. Getline is actually portable and compiles on Windows, too.