# Remove new line character from console

Tags: c, io, getchar, fflush

I have this loop, but when i hit enter after my character, it processes it and then processes the '\n' before asking for input again. Please!!!! Help

```
int input;



      while (true){
        input = getchar(); 
        fflush(NULL);
        input = input - '0';
        if( input != 'e' && input != '\n') {
            rc = state_fun(input);
        }
```

`5[ENTER]` processes 5 as input, then 10 (which is ascii '\n') as input, then requests input again.  It is driving me nuts

Comment: add a dummy getchar() at the end of while loop to consume that '\n'

Comment: The portable way to flush stdin is `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` . `fflush(NULL)` won't flush `stdin` because the standards say that `fflush(stdin);` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: you''ve just subtracted `'0'` from `input`. After that you test that *resulting value* against `e` or `\n`, thus if you press `:` it will make the condition true

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off echoing function of the console and only echo back a character if it is not `'\n'`. If you use linux, you can use this code:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    struct termios old, new;
    int nread;

    /* Turn echoing off and fail if we can't. */
    if (tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &old) != 0)
      return -1;
    new = old;
    new.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
    if (tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &new) != 0)
      return -1;

    char input;
    while (1)
    {
        input = getchar();
        if (input!='\n')
            putchar(input);
    }

    /* Restore terminal. */
    tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &old);
}
```

Refer to [Hide password input on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

```
int input;
while(true) {
    input = getchar();
    getchar(); // <------
    fflush(NULL);
    input = input - '0';
    if( input != 'e' && input != '\n') {
        rc = state_fun(input);
    }
}
```

Adding an extra `getchar()` will solve your problem. This is because <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> puts 2 characters on `stdin`: a `'5'` and a `'\n'`, which you may not expect.