# C++ strange compiler error if <unistd.h> is included

Tags: c++, c++11

Everything worked and compiled fine until I `#include <unistd.h>` (this is the single modification in my cpp) which completly breaks everything:

> test.cpp:173:33: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::thread::thread(, int, int,
>   int)’
>        std::thread t1(read, 1, 0, 3),
>                                    ^ test.cpp:173:33: note: candidates are: In file included from test.cpp:6:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:133:7: note: template std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
>          thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
>
> [200 more similar lines]

Without `#include <unistd.h>` everything works and compiles but I need it for https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856689/1879409

Note: I installed ncurses before via apt-get, maybe this broke my env?

Comment: It looks like your `read` has been overloaded: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/read.html

Comment: sounds like `<unistd.h>` adds a `read` function to the global namespace.  What `read` function are you using with `std::thread t1(read, 1, 0, 3)`?

Comment: @OP do note when you edit the error message to not be a code block it is hard to read and it removes information from the message.  For example <unresolved overloaded function type>` is removed as it is treated as a HTML tag.

Comment: I suppose is a method conflict going on into your code when including unistd

Comment: @krzaq you were right thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

> ```
> std::thread t1(read, 1, 0, 3)
> ```

You pass a function pointer to the function `read` to the constructor of `std::thread`.

[unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) declares the function: `ssize_t read(int, void *, size_t)`.

As can be seen from the error message, you have overloads for the `read` function. The one that you used before including unistd.h is not the same as what unistd.h declares. An overloaded function cannot be implicitly converted into a function pointer, because the compiler cannot know which `read` function you intended to use.

You can explicitly cast the identifier to a function pointer of correct type to resolve the ambiguity.