# How to detect when a key is press using Linux system calls

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am trying to write a C program that uses Linux system calls to emulate the behaviour of the `more` command in the Linux terminal. Since the users might enter commands such as `q` to finish the execution, I am trying to find a way in which to read keystrokes from the standard inout without using `read(...)`, as I don't want the pressed key to appear on the standard output.

In other words, I want to be able to detect pressed keys without them being written.

I have read that `ioctl()` and the `termios` struct can somehow be used for this purpose, but I am not sure how they are used (I find the man pages somewhat cryptic).

I have found a few answers to the use of those functions, but all of them seem too complicated. There must be an easier way to detect simple keystrokes, isn't there?

Comment: You could probably just use [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Or look at the source code for `more` (or `less`) and see how they handle user input ?

Answer (score 2):

`man 3 termios`, `tcsetattr`, disable `ECHO` on stdin.

For a longer explanation see: [Hide password input on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal)

Alternatively, you could go through below termios abstraction, use input layer, `/dev/input/*`, but I think you'll need to disable forwarding events from your input devices to upper layers then.