# Masking the characters of a password in a C program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, stdio

I'm trying to create a program that obscures the characters entered when entering the password. But I still have a problem, as soon as I start the program, '*' characters are continuously written up to a segmentation fault. This is the code that I wrote and the behavior of the program after execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define ENTER 13
#define TAB 9

char pwd[100];

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter your password. Hit ENTER to confirm.\n");
    printf("Password:");

    while(getch() != ENTER){
        ch = getch();
        pwd[i++] = ch;
        printf("* \b");
    }
    if(ch == ENTER || ch == TAB){
        pwd[i] = '\0';
    }

    printf("\n\nPassword:%s\nLength:%d\n\n", pwd, i);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide password input on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856635/hide-password-input-on-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to call `initscr();` before you start using any ncurses methods. So, try doing this:

```
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    initscr();
    // ...
```

More [information](https://linux.die.net/man/3/initscr).

Comment: I tried but i get this when starting the program:`Enter your password. Hit ENTER to confirm.
Password:(B)0`

Comment: @tecn603 -- OK, but this solved the issue you were having in your question, correct?

Comment: inserting `initscr ();` the asterisks are no longer printed, but the program does not work anyway, if I insert characters they are not obscured

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you asked about. :)   Anyway, I think you need to call `noecho()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting `ERR` returned from `getch()`.

That is not equal to `ENTER`, so the loop is entered and repeated. Eventually, you run out of room in `pwd`, but continue writing outside it. The segmentation fault means that you tried to write some address that is unwriteable.

You also have a bug in that you call `getch()` twice per loop, which will give you trouble even after fixing the loop/segfault issue.

Comment: I have imagined that the segmentation fault depends on the fact that I try to write to other memory addresses, but in reality, however, the program tries to write even if I do not insert any input. From what I see it looks like getch () returns -1

Comment: That is the [value of `ERR`](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/include/curses.h.in#L368).

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
while(getch() != ENTER){
    ch = getch();
```

this gets 2 characters every pass through the loop.  Not what you want.  Suggest:

```
while( ( ch = getch() ) != ENTER ){
```

To avoid echoing the char when the user enters it:
You need to turn echo `off` then for each char entered by the user, output a masking character, like `*`

since the array `pwd[]` is only 100 characters long, need to limit the number of characters the user can enter to 99 (leaves room for the trailing NUL byte)   Suggest:

```
 WINDOW *mainwin;
 mainwin = initscr();   /* start the curses mode with default window */
 clear()    /* clear the default window */
 ...
 raw();     /* stop terminal driver from interpreting key strokes */ 
 cbreak();  /* input chars without waiting for newline */
 
 nodelay( mainwin, true); /* causes getch() to wait for a key rather than returning ERR */
 keypad( mainwin, true ); /* program must handle all meta keys including newline */

 noecho();  /* stop terminal echo while entering password */

 size_t i = 0;
 while( i < (sizeof( pwd ) -1) && ( ch = getch() ) != ENTER )
 {
     pwd[i] = ch;
     i++;

     printw( "*" );
     refresh();
 }

 echo();               /* resume echoing characters on terminal */
 keypad( mainwin, false );      /* stop passing keypad chars to program */
 noraw();              /* terminal driver resumes interpreting key strokes */

 pwd[i] = '\0';        /* NUL terminate the string */   
 ...
 endwin();
```

The above may be a bit of overkill.

due to several problems, suggest NOT using the C library function: `getpass()`

if you use the `raw()` function, then the program will also need to handle backspace (and similar) characters from the user.